# Redirect /file-name to file-name.php in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

My structure project

```
- index.php
- abc.php
- folder/
---- def.php
```

My nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /index.php {
        include        snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

How can I change nginx.conf to use `domain/abc` for href instead of `domain/abc.php`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The high-performance solution is simply specifying the desired location, and map it to the corresponding PHP script.

```
location = /abc {
    include        snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/abc.php;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

This will ensure that `/abc` is processed by script `/abc.php`.

If you want to also "hide" access to `/abc.php`, you can add:

```
location = /abc.php { 
    return 404;
}
```

Why this is fast, is because the exact matching (with equals sign) involves no prefix matching and no regular expression processing.

Moreover we don't need to use `try_files` (it has [performance issues](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too)). Specifically, if using the config from the answer by @RichardSmith, it may yield up to 5 unnecessary file existence checks for an arbitrary request, and 3 file existence checks for every request to `/abc`.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly called "extensionless PHP", there are many solutions, of which this is just one:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
}
location @php {
    try_files $uri.php $uri/index.php /index.php =404;

    include        snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

If you want URIs ending in `.php` to work too, add:

```
location ~* ^(.*)\.php$ { return 301 $1$is_args$args; }
```